# Pandas Python : Why mean() function doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I create pandas 4 * 4 Dataframe(name it df) with numbers and alphabets Numpy array.
I replace non-numeric to np.nan, and want to calculate mean value of each column.
The problem is if I use mean() function for each column, a typeError appear and it doesn't work

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [ 1. ,'a', 2. , 4. , 'b', 3. , 5. , 6. , 'c', 6. , 2. , 'a', 3. , 'a', 7. , 'b']

#Create Numpy Array
np_array = np.array(data).reshape(4,4)

#Create DataFrame 4*4
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array.reshape(4,4))

#Replace non-numeric to NaN
df.replace({"a":np.nan, "b":np.nan, "c":np.nan}, inplace=True)

#Try to get mean value from df[1]
mean_value = df[1].mean() #Type Error! Why!
print(mean_value)
```

when I just enter the NaN value into the data array. df[1].mean() function works!

I want to know why the code above is not working
and why it is working if I change array value(non-numeric to NaN)

And Sorry for my poor English

Comment: because all your values are *strings*. checkout `df.iat[1,1]`

Comment: Look at `np_array` itself?  Does it show numbers, or strings (quoted `'1'`)?

Comment: "numbers and alphabets Numpy array" it is a `dtype='<U32'` array. i.e. unicode strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting using [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `coerce` option to convert non-numeric value to NaN and then calculating mean.

```
pd.to_numeric(df[1], errors='coerce').mean()
```

Output:

```
4.5
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create the numpy array from your list `data`, numpy tries to infer what the type of the array should be. When `data` contains both integers and strings, it converts everything to a string:

```
>>> data = [ 1. ,'a', 2. , 4. , 'b', 3. , 5. , 6. , 'c', 6. , 2. , 'a', 3. , 'a', 7. , 'b']
>>> np.array(data).reshape(4,4)
array([['1.0', 'a', '2.0', '4.0'],
       ['b', '3.0', '5.0', '6.0'],
       ['c', '6.0', '2.0', 'a'],
       ['3.0', 'a', '7.0', 'b']], dtype='<U32')
```

See how the numbers are now quoted? But when you replace the letters with `np.nan` in `data`, then numpy infers the data type as numerical and it works.

```
>>> data = [ 1. ,np.nan, 2. , 4. , np.nan, 3. , 5. , 6. , np.nan, 6. , 2. , np.nan, 3. , np.nan, 7. , np.nan]
>>> np.array(data).reshape(4,4)
array([[ 1., nan,  2.,  4.],
       [nan,  3.,  5.,  6.],
       [nan,  6.,  2., nan],
       [ 3., nan,  7., nan]])
```

SomeDude's answer is correct to fix it, I just wanted to provide the reason why this is happening.